# python call subprocess ren

Tags: python, batch-file, rename

I tried to rename an existing file in python using a batch command but get the following error:

> `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'`

using this code:

```
import subprocess
from time import gmtime, strftime
now = strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H:%M:%S", gmtime())
src = "C:\Users\Murph\xxx_yyy_.jpg"
dst = "xxx_yyy_zzz_" + now + "_.jpg"
subprocess.call('ren %s %s'%(src,dst), shell=True)
```

then I tried a different code and got this error: SyntaxError: ("no viable alternative at input ''%s''",

different code:

```
import os 
os.system(ren '%s','%s' < %(src,dst))
```

What am I missing?

Error code1:

```
[error] Abgebrochen
[error] Ein Fehler in Zeile 17
[error] Fehlermeldung: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Murph\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-tmp8294784858223312402.py", 
line 17, in 
subprocess.call('ren %s %s'%(src,dst), shell=True)
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", 
line 456, in call
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", 
line 751, in __init__
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", 
line 1236, in _execute_child
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'
```

Error code2:

```
[error] Abgebrochen
[error] Ein Fehler in Zeile 17
[error] Fehlermeldung: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Murph\AppData\Local\Temp\sikuli-tmp6179560160671230371.py", 
line 17, in 
os.system('ren %s %s' %(src,dst))
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", 
line 456, in call
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", 
line 751, in __init__
File "D:\Program Files (x86)\Sikuli X\sikuli-script.jar\Lib\subprocess.py", 
line 1236, in _execute_child
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'list'
```

Comment: Didn't python given you an entire stack trace showing which line failed? That should be shared.

Comment: I don't see any way that first example results in that error.

Comment: Yes. The last lines failed. So subprocess ... and os.system ...

Comment: And I used this code in sikuli which uses jython 2.5 I think.

Comment: Post the full stack trace so we can see what's going on. It really helps narrow down problems. After fixing a problem with your source path... `src = "C:\\Users\\Murph\\xxx_yyy_.jpg"` your program did not raise that error for me.

Comment: As for your second problem, try `os.system('ren %s %s'  %(src,dst))`

Comment: Ok. I posted the errors.

Comment: Very strange. This works in cpython and I can't imagine what is going wrong with jython... . but I don't use jython so can't help any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is related to Jython 2.5 subprocess module: [Error link](https://answers.launchpad.net/sikuli/+question/273629)

You should use Sikuli's latest version. ***(currently the version is 1.1.1 and Python language level 2.7 'supported by Jython')***